# Count item in tuple in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is any better solution to count item in dict like this:

`D={('a','b','c'):4,('b','c'):2}`

The dict key is tuple of items and the value is the occurrence of the tuple. How to count the occurrence of items. Example like `func(D)` should return `{'a':4,'b':6,'c':6}`.

Baseline Solution:

```
from collections import Counter
def func(D):
    f=lambda item:list(item[0])*item[1]
    L=[]
    for item in D.items():
        L+=f(item)
    return Counter(L)
```

Comment: Better than what?  What's the baseline solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following nested loop:

```
s = {}
for t, c in D.items():
    for i in t:
        s[i] = s.get(i, 0) + c
```

`s` would become:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import collections as ct
>>> D={('a','b','c'):4,('b','c'):2,}
>>> listOfElements = []
>>> for key in D:
...   listOfElements += list(key)*D[key]
...
>>> dict(ct.Counter(listOfElements))
{'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 6}
```

I hope this solves your question.